# How can css selectors be reused for multiple html pages?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing my uni project - a website. I've started to see a lot of code repeated - almost the same style details inside the {}, just the selector's name has a slight difference in the name. My questions is how can I reuse the initial selectors without repeating all the details inside?

E.g. this is for my 'Home' page:

```
.banner-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 512px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url(pexels-florencia-potter-351300-bicycle-banner.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 20%);
    z-index: -1;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

and this is for the 'Contact us' page:

```
.contacts-banner-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 512px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url(pexels-burst-374085.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 20%);
    z-index: -1;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

I know repetition is a bad thing, but I couldn't find any tips on how to avoid that in similar cases.

Comment: So use a common class name for repeated properties? class="banner contacts" class="banner funky-chicken-dinner"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single class for all of the repeating properties instead:

```
.fixed-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 512px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 20%);
    z-index: -1;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.banner-container {
    background-image: url(pexels-florencia-potter-351300-bicycle-banner.jpg);
}
.contacts-banner-container {
    background-image: url(pexels-burst-374085.jpg);
}
```

Then give the elements both the `fixed-image` class and the appropriate other class. (Rename the class as appropriate, you'll probably want something more specific than `fixed-image`.)

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful, now the css file looks better.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind, You can keep your stylesheet in a separate file.  You can call it whatever you want (i.e. `styles.css`) and then have that file imported into your HTML files.

For example:

**style.css** -> the same file will be used on all HTML files for a consistent look

```
h1 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

p {
  color: green;
}
```

**Index.html** -> here we import the CSS file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <h1>This is a heading for index.html</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph for index.html</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

And then:

**contact.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <h1>This is a heading for contact.html</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph for contact.html.</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Also, in your `styles.css` file you can combine shared attributes by separating them with commas.  In the example below, the border is the same for all containers, so I only define it once.  However, the colors are different so I create a new class for those containers where there is a need for different color, width, height, etc. (to override the original attribute value)

I.e.

```css
.my-container,
.your-container,
.their-container {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.your-container {
  color: red;
  width: 200px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.their-container {
  color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  My Container
</div>

<div class="your-container">
  yOur container
</div>

<div class="their-container">
  Their Container
</div>
```